# Проблема обработки пересечения Rectangle-ов (текстур)

Tags: android, разработка-игр, libgdx

Делаю простенькую игрушку. Логика заключается в том, что у левого края экрана стоит объект, назовем его человеком для удобства. У правого края хаотичным образом спавнятся другие объекты, для удобства, назовем их зомби. Человек убивает их из постоянно стреляющего автомата, "пули" которого при пересечении с "зомби" должны удалять "зомби" с экрана.

Проблема заключается в том, что эти "пули" просто пролетают мимо "зомби". То-есть, я не могу отследить пересечения рендеров "пуль" и "зомби".

Как я понял, проблема в многочисленном объявлении `Rectangle`-ов "зомби" и "пуль", что приводит к неразберихе в коде и той проблеме, что у меня, в частности. Есть ли возможность объявить его только 1 раз и потом всюду использовать? Если да, то как?

Кстати, просто объявить его на уровне на уровне класса, как тот же `Rectangle` человека не получается, ибо вылетает `NullPointerException`, со ссылкой на `spawncrowd` и `spavbullet`. Заранее спасибо_)

`import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Input;`

`import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.MathUtils;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector3;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Array;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.TimeUtils;`

`import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Rectangle;
import java.util.Iterator;`


`public class  MyGdxGame extends ApplicationAdapter {
    OrthographicCamera camera;
    SpriteBatch batch;`

    `Texture manImage, bulletImage, CrowdImage;
    Rectangle manRect;
    Vector3 touchPos;
    Array<Rectangle> bulletsArray, CrowdElemArray;`

```
long lastbultime, lastcrowdeltime;
int counter_miss;

@Override
public void create () {

    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    camera.setToOrtho(false, 960, 540);

    touchPos = new Vector3();

    batch = new SpriteBatch();

    manImage = new Texture("man.jpg");
    bulletImage = new Texture("bullet.jpg");
    CrowdImage = new Texture("Crowd.jpg");

    manRect = new Rectangle();
    manRect.x = 0;
    manRect.y = 540/2;
    manRect.height = 256;
    manRect.width = 256;

    CrowdElemArray = new Array<Rectangle>();
    spawncrowdel();
    bulletsArray = new Array<Rectangle>();
    spawnbullet();
}

public void spawncrowdel() {
    Rectangle CrowdelementRect = new Rectangle();
    CrowdelementRect.y = MathUtils.random(0, 540-256);
    CrowdelementRect.x = 960;
    CrowdelementRect.height = 256;
    CrowdelementRect.width = 64;
    CrowdElemArray.add(CrowdelementRect);
    lastcrowdeltime = TimeUtils.nanoTime();

}
public void spawnbullet() {
    Rectangle bulletRect = new Rectangle();
    bulletRect.y = manRect.getY() + manRect.height/2;
    bulletRect.x = manRect.getX();
    bulletRect.height = 256;
    bulletRect.width = 64;
    bulletsArray.add(bulletRect);
    lastbultime = TimeUtils.nanoTime();

}

@Override
public void render () {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 1, 0.5f, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    camera.update();
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

    batch.begin();

    batch.draw(manImage, manRect.x, manRect.y);

    for (Rectangle CrowdelementRect: CrowdElemArray) batch.draw(CrowdImage, CrowdelementRect.x, CrowdelementRect.y);
    for (Rectangle bulletRect: bulletsArray) batch.draw(bulletImage, bulletRect.x, bulletRect.y);

    batch.end();


    // Сенсорное урправление
    if (Gdx.input.isTouched()){
        touchPos.set(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0);
        camera.unproject(touchPos);
        manRect.y = (int) (touchPos.y - 128/2);
    }

    if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.UP)) manRect.y += 200 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
    if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.DOWN)) manRect.y -= 200 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();


    if (manRect.y < 0) manRect.y = 0;
    if (manRect.y > 540-256) manRect.y = 540-256;

    //TODO Спавнинг зомби
    if (TimeUtils.nanoTime() - lastcrowdeltime > 2000000000) spawncrowdel();
    //TODO Спавнинг пули
    if (TimeUtils.nanoTime() - lastbultime > 800000000) spawnbullet();

    //TODO Движение зомби
    Iterator<Rectangle> move = CrowdElemArray.iterator();
    while (move.hasNext()){
        Rectangle CrowdelementRect = new Rectangle();
        CrowdelementRect = move.next();
        CrowdelementRect.x -= 100 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        if (CrowdelementRect.x <= 10) {
            counter_miss += 1;
            move.remove();
        }
        if (CrowdelementRect.overlaps(manRect)) move.remove();
    }

    //TODO Движение пули
    Iterator<Rectangle> movebul = bulletsArray.iterator();
    Rectangle CrowdelementRect = new Rectangle();
    while (movebul.hasNext()){
        Rectangle bulletRect = movebul.next();
        bulletRect.x += 100 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        if (bulletRect.x > 960) {
            movebul.remove();
        }
        if (bulletRect.overlaps(CrowdelementRect)) movebul.remove();
    }
}
@Override
public void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    CrowdImage.dispose();
    manImage.dispose();
    bulletImage.dispose();
    batch.dispose();
}
```

}
`

PS

Делал все по шаблону со "стартандроида".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Решение взято [отсюда](https://habrahabr.ru/post/136802/). Человек решает аналогичную задачу через следующий код:

```
   private void testCollision() {
    Iterator<Bullet> b = ball.iterator();
    while(b.hasNext()) {
        Bullet balls = b.next();
        Iterator<Enemy> i = enemy.iterator();
        while(i.hasNext()) {
              Enemy enemies = i.next();

             if ((Math.abs(balls.x - enemies.x) <= (balls.width + enemies.width) / 2f)
                     && (Math.abs(balls.y - enemies.y) <= (balls.height + enemies.height) / 2f)) {
                       i.remove();
                       b.remove();
             }
        }
    }
}
```

когда-то пробовал сам - у меня работало.

Comment: @AbrogPetrovixh Все работает, только надо изменить `Enemy` и `Bullet` на `Rectangle`, а также прописать данный метод в `render`. Спасибо)

Answer (score 0):

В классе Rectangle есть метод overlaps(Rectangle anotherRectangle)
У путль есть массив и у "зомби" есть массив.
Прогоняем массив пуль, если координата X пули < (screenWidth - zimbieWidth), то проверяем следующую пулю. Если условие не верно то данную пулю гоним по массиву зомби, где выполняем:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < zombies.size; i++) {
        if (bullet.overlaps(zombie.get(rect)[i])) {
            bullet.destroy();
            zombie.destroy();
        }
    }
```