# Уничтожение объектов libGDX

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Доброго времени суток. Начал изучать libGDX. Начал с серии [данных уроков](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/508228/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-rectangle-%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80).
Решил сделать игру наподобии аркады, уничтожать лазерами вражеские корабли. Вроде бы все получилось, только вот недостаток: в момент попадания по вражескому кораблю корабль уничтожается, а лазер летит дальше. Дописал в коде `iter_laser.remove();`. В приведенном ниже коде вроде и прописано убирать и корабль и лазер, но в момент попадания уничтожается сначала лазер и получается, что `iter_enemy.remove();` не срабатывает, т.к не с чем сталкиваться.

```
Iterator<Rectangle> iter_enemy = ship_enemy_arr.iterator();
    while (iter_enemy.hasNext()){
        Rectangle enemy = iter_enemy.next();
        enemy.y = enemy.y - 50 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        if(enemy.y < 0 - 64)iter_enemy.remove();
        for(Rectangle laser: lasers) {
            if (enemy.overlaps(laser)) {
                iter_enemy.remove();
            }
        }
    }

Iterator<Rectangle> iter_laser = lasers.iterator();
    while (iter_laser.hasNext()){
        Rectangle lasers = iter_laser.next();
        lasers.y = lasers.y + 400 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        if(lasers.y > 480)iter_laser.remove();
        for(Rectangle enemy: ship_enemy_arr) {
            if (lasers.overlaps(enemy)) {
                iter_laser.remove();
            }
        }
    }
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как в момент попадания убирать и лазер?

**UPD**

Решение нашел из [этой темы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/508228/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-rectangle-%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80). Правда опять же непонятица вылезла: при запуске игры скорость лазера ускоряется с каждой итерацией вражеского корабля... Как поправить?

Получился код:

```
Iterator<Rectangle> iter_enemy = ship_enemy_arr.iterator();
    while (iter_enemy.hasNext()){
        Rectangle enemy = iter_enemy.next();
        Iterator<Rectangle> iter_laser = lasers.iterator();
        while (iter_laser.hasNext()){
            Rectangle lasers = iter_laser.next();
            if (enemy.overlaps(lasers)) {
                iter_enemy.remove();
                iter_laser.remove();
            } else {
                lasers.y = lasers.y + 200 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
                if(lasers.y > 480){
                    iter_laser.remove();
                }
            }
        }
        enemy.y = enemy.y - 50 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        if(enemy.y < 0 - 64)iter_enemy.remove();
    }
```

Comment: Почему бы не итерироваться сразу по "врагам" и по "лазерам" и удалять оба при столкновении?

Comment: @Nofate, здравствуйте! Я пробовал совмещать эти два кода и так и сяк, перемешивал пытаясь добиться нужного результата, но ввиду моей малоопытности в libGDX постоянно получал краш приложения либо сразу, либо через 1-2 сек после запуска. Если Вас не затруднит, модифицируйте данный код как надо. Буду очень Вам благодарен.

Comment: По-хорошему поиск коллизий и обновление состояния игровых объектов вам бы раскинуть по разным циклам.

Comment: @Nofate Получится же такой момент, как в начале топика...

Comment: будет два цикла, но других

Comment: @Nofate, мои манипуляции с кодом все равно в итоге приводят практически к такому же виду и скорость лазера ускоряется. Помогите, пожалуйста, составить правильный код.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте как-то так:

```
Iterator<Rectangle> iter_enemy = ship_enemy_arr.iterator();
Iterator<Rectangle> iter_laser = lasers.iterator();
while (iter_enemy.hasNext()){
    Rectangle enemy = iter_enemy.next();
    while (iter_laser.hasNext()){
        Rectangle lasers = iter_laser.next();
        if (enemy.overlaps(laser)) {
            iter_enemy.remove();
            iter_laser.remove();
        } else {
            lasers.y = lasers.y + 400 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
            if(lasers.y > 480)iter_laser.remove();
        }
    }
    enemy.y = enemy.y - 50 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
    if(enemy.y < 0 - 64)iter_enemy.remove();
}
```

Comment: Видимо в строке `if (enemy.overlaps(laser)) {` надо вместо `laser` написать `lasers`, т.к `laser` нету. При запуске уничтожается от 1 до 4 кораблей с уничтожением и корабля и лазера, а далее лазеры просто пролетают сквозь...

Comment: Нашел решение, обновил первый пост, но есть еще проблемка, там написал.